# TLP does not drain battery when using thresholds

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, thinkpad, tlp

I'm using **Thinkpad T460** with Debian Buster.

I installed tlp and set the battery thresholds to **start charging at 75% and stop at 85%**.

```
# Battery charge thresholds (ThinkPad only, tp-smapi or acpi-call kernel module
# required). Charging starts when the remaining capacity falls below the
# START_CHARGE_THRESH value and stops when exceeding the STOP_CHARGE_THRESH value.
# Main / Internal battery (values in %)
START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=75
STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=85
# Ultrabay / Slice / Replaceable battery (values in %)
START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT1=75
STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT1=85
```

It works fine except that it doesn't start discharging when reaches the threshold limit. The charging stops but **it stuck at 85% and never gets below**. It seems it uses AC only when reached the limit.

Am I misunderstanding the thresholds' behaviour, or this is just a bug?

Comment: That's how TLP works. When it reaches the upper limit, it switches to AC power to keep the charge level. It only discharges when you unplug the AC, and then it will only start charging again when you plug it in below the lower threshold. It's explained somewhere in the [TLP doc](https://linrunner.de/tlp/).

Comment: @Sebastian : almost right: this it the behaviour the *hardware* determines.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding on your part. The [FAQ](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html#why-does-the-battery-not-start-to-discharge-when-the-stop-threshold-is-reached-during-charging) explains it:

> **Why does the battery not start to discharge when the stop threshold is
> reached during charging?**
>
> The task of the stop threshold is to reduce battery wear by limiting
> the charge level below 100%. So charging stops at the threshold and
> the battery will not be discharged as long as the charger remains
> connected.
>
> This is the behaviour defined by Lenovo. It is hard-coded into the EC
> firmware (see above) and behaves identically for the pre-loaded OS.
>
> In contrast, repeated discharge of the battery during operation on AC
> power would lead to absurdly high wear (i.e. charging cycles) without
> any benefit being derived from it.